# iOS objective c webview - enable debugging so it can be debugged once on the iTunes store

Tags: ios, objective-c, debugging, webview, itunes

This is a strange one however I need to enable an application that is submitted to iTunes to allow for debugging "inspector" in the webviews.  Need to allow users that download the application to debug the webview because specific webviews will be the users source.

I can't seem to find how I could do this.  Of course after building the binary you can't inspect the applications webviews.

Anyone ever have to do something like this?  Any information would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What are you wanting to debug? Is it the webview itself or the content (webpage) in the webview?

Comment: Just want to allow for debugging the content of the webview(s) (js, html, etc).

Comment: Are you wanting to debug on the device itself or are you wanting to debug on mac with the device plugged in? If you are wanting to debug on the mac with the device plugged in then that's all up to the user they have to enable web inspector on the device in settings and then use the developer tools in safari (Mac version) to inspector the webview on the device so nothing that you can do. Have a look at http://moduscreate.com/enable-remote-web-inspector-in-ios-6/

Comment: I know you can connect your device to your mac and debug with safari.  However this is an app that was build and is on the iTunes store.  Once its on the store and you download it you can't debug the webviews in the app.  I understand why it would be like that and agree with it however in my instance I need to have the webviews inside the built app on iTunes inspect-able.  So prior to pushing the binary to iTunes the webviews are inspect-able however once the binary is placed on iTunes and the user downloads the application the webviews are not inspect-able.

Comment: Sorry but no its not possible.

Comment: Thats what I thought.  Thanks for taking the time.